# Java docs not available on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I setup Spring boot project with Java 8 on IntelliJ latest version (2018.2). I was able to do download Spring documentation using `Maven->Download Sources and Documentation`. But Java docs are not available in my project when I do CTRL+Click, all I see is the source code of the class. When docs loaded properly, we should be able to see documentation on top of method definition. I checked `Project Structure -> SDK -> Documentation paths` and it has valid URL to [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). When I clicked on any class, all I see is source code for the class but documentation is missing. I tried to include docs from the Oracle website manually, it did not work either. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 operating system.

[image: Decompiled class file]

[image: SDKS]

[image: Spring Data documentation]

Comment: For starters, you're looking at the decompiled version of that class, which would never contain comments...

Comment: Well, when I do CTRL+Click, this is where it took me. It works for Spring classes, not sure, what's wrong here

Comment: IntelliJ's default kay map differs by platform and I use a Mac. That being said what happens if you put the cursor on a method and press the F1 key?

Comment: @HairOfTheDog I think this issue is related to IntelliJ loading docs, not a key combination. Because Spring docs working with same key combination

Comment: I made that suggestion because I expect control-click to navigate to method definition, not JavaDoc. I expect F1 to open the JavaDoc for a method. Give it a try.

Comment: @HairOfTheDog it did not work

Comment: @HairOfTheDog One more observation, when you load Java docs, method definition has documentation on top of it.

Comment: @jadda what is shown on the Sourcepath tab in the Project Structure window?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's empty. https://imgur.com/a/Rv2Y4tj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs URL setting has nothing to do with the code you see when you navigate to a class from the Java API. Rather, you can place your cursor in a class or method name and press Ctrl+Q to view the documentation in a popup window.

Comment: You are right, I can see the documentation with CTRL+Q. Is there a way to see the documentation similar to Spring documentation (just above the method or class)?

Comment: @Jadda As others stated in previous comments, you are seeing decompiled source code. You need to point the Sourcepath to actual source code which might allow you to see the docs directly in source.

Comment: He's not seeing decompiled source code. He's seeing the actual source code which is why he also sees JavaDoc. Likely for Spring he downloaded all three Jar files; classes, javadoc and source

Comment: @HairOfTheDog The screenshot for FileInputStream.class doesn't show any JavaDocs. And because of the `.class` extension appears to be decompiled.

Comment: @HairOfTheDog I am able to see the documentation on macOS without any issues

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I figured out the issue. In my Ubuntu machine, I installed open-jdk8 and added as SDK. But it did not download sources along with JDK. I  tried download the sources manually, I got 404 on OpenJDK website. So, uninstalled OpenJDK and installed Oracle JDK. Everything works now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Jadda Feel free to post an answer to explain what you did to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. In my Ubuntu machine, I installed open-jdk8 and added as SDK in IntelliJ. But OpenJDK did not download sources along with JDK. I tried to download the sources manually, but I got 404 on OpenJDK sources website. So, uninstalled OpenJDK and installed Oracle JDK. Everything works now. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Fedora 31

download zip from page https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11 
(for Java 11, for Java 13, replace with "/13" etc.)

or direct link for Java 11:
https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_src.zip

save in a custom location, e.g. ~/java/sources

open IntelliJ Idea's 
Project Structure -> SDKs -> Sourcepath
point point to the zip
e.g. ~/java/sources/openjdk-11+28_src.zip

now Ctrl+Q opens real javadoc in the editor